# AmplifyException on flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-amplify

Please does anyone know why i keep getting amplifyexception even after following the entire process stated in the documentation

> AmplifyException(message: Amplify plugin AmplifyAuthCognitoMethodChannel was not added successfully., recoverySuggestion: We currently don't have a recovery suggestion for this exception., underlyingException: AmplifyException(message: Category auth has already been configured or is configuring., recoverySuggestion: Make sure that you have added all plugins before attempting configuration., underlyingException: null))

I already initialized it

```
Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {
    if (!_isConfigured) {
      try {
        await Amplify.addPlugins([
          AmplifyAuthCognito(),
          AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: ModelProvider.instance),
          AmplifyAPI(),
          AmplifyStorageS3(),
        ]);

        // call Amplify.configure to use the initialized categories in your app
        await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
        setState(() => _isConfigured = true);
        log("initialized");
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        log('An error occurred configuring Amplify: $e');
      }
    }
  }
```

and this are in my pubspec.yaml file

> amplify_api: ^0.6.2
> amplify_auth_cognito: ^0.6.2
> amplify_datastore: ^0.6.2
> amplify_flutter: ^0.6.2
> amplify_storage_s3: ^0.6.2

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are not adding all the plugins listed in your pubspec.yaml

e.g. Storage & Analytics